# How to connect socketIO in flutter?

Tags: flutter, sockets, dart, server

I'm trying to add chat functionality in my app using [socket_io_client](https://pub.dev/packages/socket_io_client) plugin but Unable to connect to the socket. it neither throws error or nor exception . In fact not printing response after get connection . so I'm confused, it connected or not?
and I'm not familiar with socketIO, means I never did it before .

Dunno what am I doing wrong .

Piece of Code:

```
import 'package:socket_io_client/socket_io_client.dart' as IO;
```

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _messageController = TextEditingController();
    _controller = ScrollController();
    connectSocket();

  }


 connectSocket() async {
     print('Connecting to chat service');
    socket = IO.io('http://....', <String, dynamic>{
      'transports': ['websocket'],
      'autoConnect': false,
    });
    socket.connect();
    socket.on('connection', (data) {
      print('connect:$data');

    });
  }
```

Comment: but @GursewakSingh I'm not using web socket. I'm using socket.io